# Failing to read data from s3 to a spark dataframe in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to read a csv file on an s3 bucket (for which the sagemaker notebook has full access to) into a spark dataframe however I am hitting the following issue where `sagemaker-spark_2.11-spark_2.2.0-1.1.1.jar` can't be found. Any tips on how to resolve this is appreciate!

```
bucket = "mybucket"
prefix = "folder/file.csv"
df = spark.read.csv("s3://{}/{}/".format(bucket,prefix))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o388.csv.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Error reading configuration file
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:309)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:596)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_pyspark/jars/sagemaker-spark_2.11-spark_2.2.0-1.1.1.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:84)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:304)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: It looks like a jupyter kernel issue. I had a similar issue and I used `Sparkmagic (pyspark)` kernel instead of `Sparkmagic (pyspark3)` and it is working fine. Follow instructions on this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/) and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks @rajesh I followed the same blog initially! But you're right this doesn't happen in `Sparkmagic (pyspark)` and it's specific to `Sparkmagic (pyspark3)`! If you'd like please have your response as an answer as this can help unblock others as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Making comment to the original question as answer)

It looks like a jupyter kernel issue. I had a similar issue and I used `Sparkmagic (pyspark)` kernel instead of `Sparkmagic (pyspark3)` and it is working fine. Follow instructions on this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/) and see if it helps.